# Connect to an https service using an http-only client

Tags: windows, proxy, http, https

Is there a simple command line client that would be invoked something like this:

```
http2https --listen localhost:80 --connect example.com:443
```

which would then allow me to effectively connect to `https://example.com` by actually connecting to `http://localhost`? It would need to work on Windows.

I have tried stunnel, but it doesn't seem to work.

**Update:**

Here's the output of `stunnel.exe -c -r google.com:443 -d 127.0.0.1:8888`

```
No limit detected for the number of clients
stunnel 4.56 on x86-pc-msvc-1500 platform
Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Threading:WIN32 Sockets:SELECT,IPv6 SSL:ENGINE,OCSP,FIPS
Reading configuration from file -c
Cannot read configuration

Syntax:
stunnel [ [-install | -uninstall] [-quiet] [<filename>] ] | -help | -version | -sockets
    <filename>  - use specified config file
    -install    - install NT service
    -uninstall  - uninstall NT service
    -quiet      - don't display a message box on success
    -help       - get config file help
    -version    - display version and defaults
    -sockets    - display default socket options

Server is down
```

Answer (score 5):

Paul had it almost right but under Windows you need to add ***client = yes*** to the config file since *-c* is not a command line parameter for windows stunnel.

The following config works for me

```
[remote]
client = yes
accept = 8888
connect = google.com:443
```

I ended up using tstunnel.exe rather than stunnel.exe since that is the command line version of stunnel in Windows. Here's the command:

```
tstunnel remote_stunnel.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

`stunnel` *is* what you are after:

```
sudo stunnel -c -r google.com:443 -d 127.0.0.1:8888
```

This sets up a SSL session to the remote party (Google in this case), and creates a listener on localhost port 8888.  You can use 80 if you don't already have a listener.

Then you access localhost:8888 and you'll get the remote site.

If you are using Windows, then command line options aren't supported, so create a file `stunnel.conf` with the parameters within:

```
[remote]
accept = 8888
connect = google.com:443
```

Then call it with

```
stunnel -c stunnel.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. The output has been added to the question.

Comment: Yes, Windows. See the post. When I'm back on my Windows machine, I'll publish a small nodejs app I wrote for this purpose.

Comment: What is there to try? You just added the windows tag. Thanks for that anyway.

Comment: Sorry - I meant the updated answer.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling there are two distinct versions of stunnel with completely different parameters. Check the output of stunnel in the question that shows the parameters that are available to be set. Nowhere is the a `-c` parameter. In fact, it says it's looking for a configuration file called `-c` because I put the `-c` option on the command line and it did not recognize it as an option.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Did you try without the -c?

Comment: Yes, I remember doing it with just a simple config. It died as soon as I hit it with a request. About to post the nodejs solution...

Comment: At my time of reading this, I'm using stunnel 4.53 running on linux and it shows a -c option as 'client mode (remote service uses SSL)' which seems to be what was suggested

Answer (score 2):

Here's a node.js script that does what I want:

```js
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    var h = req.headers;
    h.host = "www.example.com";
    var req2 = https.request({ host: h.host, port: 443, path: req.url, method: req.method, headers: h }, function (resp2) {
        resp.writeHead(resp2.statusCode, resp2.headers);
        resp2.on('data', function (d) { resp.write(d); });
        resp2.on('end', function () { resp.end(); });
    });
    req.on('data', function (d) { req2.write(d); });
    req.on('end', function () { req2.end(); });
}).listen(9999, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9999/');
```

The host and local port are both hardcoded, but it would be easy enough to make them command line parameters.